# Scanning Assemblys using StructureMap in Asp.net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, structuremap3

I using StructureMap for dependency resulution.

I have 2 projects

- Project.Web (Website)
- Project.Web.DependencyResolution (Main Registry is located here and Scanning Starts here.)

I am unable to use :

```
        Scan(
            scan =>
            {
                scan.AssembliesFromPath("bin", AssemblyFilter);
                scan.LookForRegistries();
                });
```

As this is not able to find the location and gives a Weird path for the assembly.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\project.web
\25abf8e7\23716017\assembly\dl3\7faa87f3\c3224109_5602d001
\project.Web.DependencyResolution.dll
```

Why does the assembly not able to find the `bin` directory or the directory where the project get published/compiled ??
I have treis this using IIS and IIS Express

Any help/tips to setup this structure ??
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this way:

```
Scan(
      scan =>
       {
         scan.AssembliesFromPath(Path.GetDirectoryName((new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase).LocalPath)), AssemblyFilter);
         scan.LookForRegistries();
        });
```

Comment: Great Thanks!! Your Tip helped Althought 
`scan.AssembliesFromPath(
                        Path.GetDirectoryName((new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase).LocalPath)),
                        AssemblyFilter);` I have to add changes to correct the URI path... but the `Codebase` thing totally slipped out of my mind, You can update the answer